# emmet abbrevation not working in folder named templates in vsCode

Tags: html, directory, emmet

emmet abbrevation not working in folder named templates in vsCode.

when i change the folder's name to any other name emmet starts working. I am using flask therefore i can't change the folder name other than templates. Help me out fix this

Comment: Give us an example of what you tried